# How to update (dynamic) marker-icons with live-data?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

**Hey folks**,

I was wondering, if it's possible to create marker-icons that can be updated/altered as soon as the AJAX-function pulls new data from the server. To give you an example:

I have several markers representing different people. Now if one of them posts a new message to the system, AJAX fetches it and passes is to the Map-Object. Now I'd like to pop this (event) into the map by either opening an *InfoWindow* next to that person, or - and this is the preferred way - to add a tiny red icon next to the marker-icon, just like you know it from the top-navigation in Facebook (e.g. you have 5 new messages and 3 friend requests).
And if the icon is clicked/the InfoWindow open, I'd want to remove that extra icon from it.

Is there any possibility to do this? And what would be the fastest (in terms of benchmarking) way to go with? Maybe with additional overlays? Or would I have to calculate the pixels within the viewport and add  onto it?

Now it's your turn... :)

**Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be using setIcon() function of the Marker class.

It is quite possible to use another overlay and the trick is to calculate the pixels within the viewport. You can avoid that by using a transparant 'red icon' and overlays it on top of the existing icon using the custom overlay classes (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays) by using the position of the icon.

If you really want to calculate the pixels, you can search for 'google map contextmenu' and refer to how people do the calculation.

Comment: What do you think is more appropriate in terms of speed? I am already using custom marker-icons. Creating even more icons for every single marker seems to be even worse. I like the idea of overlays, but as I'll have quite some markers, a lot of panning and zooming in the map it'd require the recalculation each time. That's got to be slow, eh? Isn't there something else? Like super-fast?

Comment: Basically I need something which is very fast with a lot of markers, panning, zooming and incoming messages? Anyone?

Comment: Using icon or custom overlay makes not too much difference if you consider about the panning and zooming. Only difference is depending on whether you use icon(image) or not. Depending on the browsers and computers, dozens of icons or small sized overlays, or even hundreds of them, can be rendered pretty fast nowadays.